# Code to replace all the tabs and if there are more than 1 space by a single space?

Tags: c

This question is in [K&R](http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628/), exercise 1.9. I wrote the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c,i=0,n=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
         if(c!=' '||c!='\t')
         {
             i=0;
             putchar(c);
         }
         else if(c==' '||c=='\t')
         {
              i++
         }
         if((c+1)!=' '||(c+1)!='\t')
               n=i;
         if(n!=0)
        {
               c=' ';
               putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

but i could not get the desired output. I am using gcc in ubuntu. When I enter something like `hello\t\ta` as input then my output is `hello\_\_a` i.e number of tab is replaced by number of space and when I enter `hello\_\_a` then my output is same as input.

Please help me with it or suggest me something new to get the desired output.

Comment: Take a look at your first 'if' the curly braces are a bit strange there.

Comment: This code does not compile: `12: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’`

Comment: c+1? what do you want to imply with this?

Comment: sorry about that.that extra { came there by mistake,it is not in the real answer.apart from that any mistake.sorry about that extra {

Comment: I wonder how many people know what `"k&r"` is. I certainly don't.

Comment: by c+1 i meant the next character.the compiler showed no error so i went ahead with it.

Comment: "C and K&R" is like "C++ and Strostrup" or "LISP and Steele". That is needd knowledge!

Comment: @Dukeling: It's fairly common knowledge in the C world: http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628/

Comment: thats why i wrote the whole problem instead of just writing k&r exercise 1.9

Comment: You need to replace all the tabs by what? By a single space?

Comment: yes i have to replace subsequent spaces by a single space.so there should be only single spaces only in the output.

Comment: somebody got an idea.show me how to do it.you may use your own codes.

Comment: "show me" (with an implied "!" instead of "please") is not the way, stackoverflow works. All answers are here, to guide you into the right direchtion, not to provide you with the complete solution!

Comment: @Peter miehle thank you and everyone else.my earlier comment 'show me' with implied ! (as you said)was quite unintentional but my thanking you all now with a smile is quite intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving your the full working program, I prefer to guide you to the right direction.

First of all, `c+1` does not mean "next character in the input". It only adds `1` to the value of `c`, which effectively converts `c` to the next character in the [ASCII table](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html).
For example if `c` is `'a'`, `c+1` means `'b'`, which is next character int the [ASCII table](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html), and if `c` is `' '` (a single space) that has a code of 32 in the table, `c+1` is `'!'` that has a code 33 in the table.

Well, to get the next character, you need to read it! In the same way you read the first character. The best way to achieve this, is to always hold the previous read character, and check that with the currently read character.

So you need two variables, for example `c` and `pc`. You read the character and store it in `c`. At first, `pc` is `'\0'`. If the read character is not space or tab, you write it to the output. If it is tab, you change it to space. And if it is space, you check the previous character (`pc`). If it is not space, print `c`. At the end of the loop, you should store the value of `c` into `pc`, which means you are holding the previous character in `pc`.

I guess I told you the complete solution!

Comment: I figured it out that it can done using a single variable too but still thank you very much.

Comment: @THEPARADOX Never economize on defining variables.

Comment: i'll certainly keep that in mind.

#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int i;
for(i=0,i>=0;i++)
printf("THANK YOU");
}

Comment: @THEPARADOX You're welcome. BTW, you should usually mark one of the answers as the accepted answer (if you are satisfied). Please read [faq] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: you want to check the NEXT character, but you check the current character's value incremented by one.

Comment: how to check the next character value ?

Comment: how did you get the current character?

Comment: the current character?through the while loop.while loop keeps on going to the next character until it reaches the end of file.

Comment: "Hilfe zur Selbsthilfe". You answered your question by answering my question.

Comment: I want to check the end of spaces that is why i used (c+1).Suppose the input is friend/_/_/_is then on reaching the third /_ i know my spaces are going to end,knowing this i could replace 3 spaces with a single space by storing the value of i(that is 3 here) into n.So n is not equal to 0 and it should print the single space and the next character is not space so i becomes 0 and i is printed.but somehow the code is not running as desired.even if i put n=0 in first if block it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is slightly wrong, here is a hint, keep the last character as *state*, if the newly entered character is a space and the last character was a space, then don't output, simply go back round the loop and wait for the next character.

If the current character is not a space, output and update the *state*...